# $HOME is not set for ec2-user during commands in User Data run

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I put the following commands in user data of an EC2 running RedHat 8 AMI (`ami-0fc841be1f929d7d1`), when they run, the mkdir tries to create .kube at root which looks to me like `$HOME` is not set at the time.

```
mkdir -p $HOME/.kube
sudo cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/.kube/config
sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.kube/config
```

Following are log from `/var/log/user-data.log`

```
+ mkdir -p /.kube
+ sudo cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf /.kube/config
++ id -u
++ id -g
+ sudo chown 0:0 /.kube/config
```

When I SSH to the instance, the `$HOME` is set correctly to /home/ec2-user.

Could you advise what I did wrong here?

Thank you

Answer (score 7):

When your EC2 server is provisioned, the user data script runs as user root, so $HOME is empty. What you could do, is to define the HOME env var at the top of your user data script, like this (insert your user's home directory here):

```
export HOME=/home/ubuntu
```

I've tried it and it works (I install NVM, SDKMAN, sbt, java, git, docker; all works fine). You might need to do some chown at the end of your user data script to change the owner of some files back to your user. For example, if your user data sets up some files in your home directory:

```
chown ubuntu ~/.foo/bar.properties
```

Answer (score 3):

`$HOME` refers to the home directory of the logged in user. Userdata runs under the root user, and the root user `$HOME` is `/`. That is the result you are seeing.

Instead of the variable `$HOME`, your script should refer to `/home` as a literal.

See https://superuser.com/questions/271925/where-is-the-home-environment-variable-set

Comment: `$HOME` for user root is `/root` not `/`

Comment: While it is true that root is the user $HOME is not defined and additionally as another user commented root's home directory is `/root` not `/`. Hard coding literals is also bad practice.

Comment: Yes In general hard coding is bad practice, but for standard file system paths `/etc` or `/var/log` or `/home` it is appropriate. Under a non-login shell as above, that is the best solution, as there is no variable called `$HOME` in that environment. If your prefer, then simply set that value at the top beginning of the userdata eg `HOME=/home`. For more info on standard file system paths see https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/5/html/deployment_guide/s1-filesystem-fhs

Answer (score 2):

You are running as sudo which is known to change environment variables that are established with your users shell (such as `$HOME`) as well as shell context based such as `ssh-agent`.

Generally you can ensure this persists when you run sudo by adding it to the `env_keep` settings in your sudoers configuration by adding the below line within `/etc/sudoers`. More information is available [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-edit-the-sudoers-file), be careful about modifying this file.

```
Defaults  env_keep=HOME
```

Otherwise if you don't want to make the above change, ensure you have the permissions to carry this out without running `sudo` or pass an **absolute path** value in.

I would generally stay clear of user data for important configuration anyway,
instead build a pre-baked AMI ahead of time with the configuration how you want it, using a configuration tool such as [Ansible](https://www.ansible.com/), [Chef](https://www.chef.io/), [Puppet](https://puppet.com/).

**Alternatively** as this is within the User Data anyway, it is unlikely you have already configured the sudoers configuration, you should instead just specify the path.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue. Adding this to the User Data script helped resolve it. The sub shells will have the HOME set with this change to profile.

```
cat > /etc/profile.d/set_home.sh << 'EOF'
export HOME=~
EOF
chmod a+x /etc/profile.d/set_home.sh
```